# How to convert and download chart to pdf?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jspdf, google-visualization

I m using jsPdf plugin and did this

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataValues,true);
         var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById(id));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
          var content = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
          $('#graph-images').append(content);
        });

function generatePDF() {
      var imageTags = $('#graph-images img');
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.setFontSize(33);
        doc.setFillColor(135, 124,45,0);
        doc.addImage(imageTags[0], 'png', 10, 10, 150, 100);
        doc.save('sample.pdf');
     }
```

by using this i am able to download the pdf file while open that pdf file in adobe reader its saying 110 error.

Can Anybody Help in this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass image URI to `addImage()`:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataValues, true)
  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById(id))
  chart.draw(data)
  imgData = chart.getImageURI()
})

function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.setFontSize(33);
  doc.setFillColor(135, 124,45,0);
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 10, 10, 150, 100);
  doc.save('sample.pdf');
}
```

Please check this live demo for more details https://jsfiddle.net/p1frmxvp/1/

**UPDATE**

Turns out the error happens only when we use jspdf [1.3.2](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js) and open the pdf using Adobe Reader as explained [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/862). The only solution so far is either opening the pdf using other viewer (Chrome, Foxit Reader .etc) or downgrading jspdf to [1.2.61](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jspdf/1.2.61). I have updated the jsfiddle above to use the downgraded jspdf.

Comment: while opening the downloaded file in adobe reader it's saying error .there was an error processing a page. there was a problem reading this document (110)?Can u help me for this ?

Comment: are you saying that you got error when opening pdf generated in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p1frmxvp/ ? If yes then the problem is in your adobe reader. I can open the pdf without any issue

Comment: okay thanks , i am going to download the latest version of Adobe reader and then i will try . Thank you.

Comment: @NitishKumar sorry, I am able to reproduce the issue with Adobe Reader (error 110). Previously I can open the pdf using Chrome & Foxit Reader. Apparently the issue is within jspdf. Is it mandatory to use it?

Comment: 100 out of 90 people basically using  Adobe Reader for read the pdf file that's why i m trying to open in Adobe reader. What's the another possibility.

Comment: I have updated the answer. In that case your only option is to downgrade jspdf